# Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function using charindex function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE testcheck
(
    id int,
    colname nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO testcheck (id, colname)
VALUES (1, 'xxx xxxxx (xx11111) | yyyy yyyyyy yyyyyyyy (yy1111)')

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname)), 
              CHARINDEX('(', RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname))) + 1, 
              CHARINDEX(')', Colname) - CHARINDEX('(', RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname))) - 1) Colname
FROM
    dbo.testcheck
```

My value is 'xxx xxxxx (xx11111) | yyyy yyyyyy yyyyyyyy (yy1111)' not sure why I get this error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

I want to extract text between brackets my complete code is as below

```
select   case when LEN(colname)=0 then '' else case when                SUBSTRING(Colname,CHARINDEX('(',Colname)+1,CHARINDEX(')',Colname)-CHARINDEX('(',Colname)-1)=
                SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)),CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)))+1,CHARINDEX(')',Colname)-CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)))-1)
                then SUBSTRING(Colname,CHARINDEX('(',Colname)+1,CHARINDEX(')',Colname)-CHARINDEX('(',Colname)-1)
                else CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Colname,CHARINDEX('(',Colname)+1,CHARINDEX(')',Colname)-CHARINDEX('(',Colname)-1),',',SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)),CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)))+1,CHARINDEX(')',RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)))-CHARINDEX('(',RIGHT(Colname,LEN(Colname)-CHARINDEX('|',Colname)))-1)) end
                 END 
          from dbo.testcheck
```

This works for most values but doesnt work for few values

Comment: Because you are passing a negative number to `LEFT` or `SUBSTRING` for the length. They only accept a 0+ value.

Comment: In truth, it looks like you've really overly complicated what you're trying to achieve here. What is your actual goal?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this just by appending

```
SUBSTRING(RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname || '|')), 
          CHARINDEX('(', RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname || '|'))) + 1, 
          CHARINDEX(')', Colname) - CHARINDEX('(', RIGHT(Colname, LEN(Colname) - CHARINDEX('|', Colname || '|'))) - 1) Colname
```

You haven't specified what the code is supposed to be doing.  But this should at least answer your question and eliminate the error.

Comment: I want to extract test within brackets .

Comment: @user3044949 . . . You should ask a *new* question and explain what you want to accomplish, with sample data and desired results.  You might as well delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solutions.

**SQL #1**

It is for SQL Server 2017 onwards.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('xxx xxxxx (xx11111) | yyyy yyyyyy yyyyyyyy (yy1111)');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, TRIM([value]) AS [row]
    FROM @tbl
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(tokens, '|')
)
SELECT ID, TRIM('()' FROM value) AS Result
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(row, SPACE(1))
WHERE LEFT(value,1) = '(';
```

**SQL #2**

It is for SQL Server 2012 onwards.

```
;WITH rs as
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
             REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
             ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
)
SELECT ID --, c
    , SUBSTRING(token, 2, LEN(token) - 2) AS Result
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/root/r[substring(./text()[1],1,1)="("]/text()') AS t2(x)
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'))) AS t3(token);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Result  |
+----+---------+
|  1 | xx11111 |
|  1 | yy1111  |
+----+---------+
```